# Swiftで音声のbinary dataをPOSTする方法

Tags: swift, ios, api, http

Swiftを使ったiOSアプリにてGoogle Speech APIを利用しようとしています。
ローカルにある音声ファイルをインプットとする場合のサンプルは以下です。

```
curl -X POST \
--data-binary @audio/good-morning-google.flac \
--header 'Content-Type: audio/x-flac; rate=44100;' \
'https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=en-us&key=yourkey'
```

同様のPOSTをSwiftで実装する方法が分からず、ご教示いただけないでしょうか。
具体的には、

```
--data-binary @audio/good-morning-google.flac \
```

と同様にローカルに保存したオーディオファイルをバイナリデータ指定で送るところが不明です。

ご参考：【Google Speech API】
https://gist.github.com/alotaiba/1730160

Comment: Google公式のドキュメントやライセンスを確認しましたか? 参考サイトを見るとリバースエンジニアリングの話ばかりでたいへん胡散臭いです。

Answer (score 1):

普通にNSMutableURLRequestのHTTPBodyにバイナリデータを入れれば良いのでは？